# Property does not exist on service

Tags: angular, function, api, methods

There is an issue with my code with a service that calls the backend API to retrieve values.  The code is below.

```
async deleteAsync(id: string) {
this.confirmationService.confirm({
  message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
  header: 'Confirm',
  icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
  accept: async () => {
    try {
      await this.siteService.deleteAsync(id, this.app.username);
      this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'Site Deleted', life: 3000 });
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Delete Site Failed', life: 3000 });
    }

    await this.refreshListAsync();
  }
});
```

}

The error message I get is Property 'deleteAsync' does not exist on type 'SiteService'.

Do I need to change the backend code in order to resolve this issue, that the method does not exist on the service?

I tried looking at the definitions in visual studio code of the method but I could not find a way to resolve this issue.

How do I define a service method that is not defined?

Comment: Yes, you can't call a service method that's not defined.

Comment: Please post complete code to the site and not images of code fragments.